# How to disable text blur in Evince?

Tags: pdf, evince

Evince blurs PDFs by default (see comparison image). Is there a way to disable this behavior? Bonus points for a solution that works on a per-document basis.

[image]

Comment: In the image, I meant "viewer" not "editor."

Comment: Can you post an example PDF that has this issue? Preferably the PDF you show above.

Comment: Can you add evince and poppler version to your question? (You can check it on Evince: Help->About).

Comment: @user4124: Any PDF will demonstrate what I am talking about. @sergio92pt: Version 2.32.0.

Comment: What are your settings in Appearance->Fonts->Rendering? Also, what is your "other viewer"? On the same OS?

Comment: @Christoph It never occurred to me that it is a system-wide setting. But disabling "sub-pixel rendering" in Appearance -> Fonts -> Rendering "fixes" the blur. I wish I could disable per-app. Can you make a quick answer so I can mark it as answered. (If you don't before my next visit, or so, I'll do it.)

Comment: @Syzygy: done that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are your settings in Appearance->Fonts->Rendering? This may be an OS setting, not the reader's fault.

OP's answer: Disabling "sub-pixel rendering" in Appearance -> Fonts -> Rendering "fixes" the blur.

Comment: I don't see that setting. I'm using GNOME Document Viewer 3.26.0. Do you know how to do it nowadays?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't.