# System-wide smoothing is off, but evince smooths anyway

Tags: fonts, evince

I managed to turn of smoothing system-wide in ubuntu (see screenshot) including font in applications.

However, `evince` (and other pdf readers) does not respect smoothing turned off and smooths text in pdf anyway. Is there way to make evince use unsmoothed text ?

[image]

Comment: I understand, but the image is not high resolution, try a different host maybe

Comment: I did post full image as attachement (I couldn't directly) but moderator altered it. Anyway, full-res image is here
http://i.imgur.com/3rDTC.png

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/51966/how-to-disable-text-blur-in-evince

Comment: I would suggest you try some other readers. Its doubtful you can fix this, without compiling.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been abandoned.